# Carrierwave with Neo4j not saving image assocation to DB

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-s3, neo4j, carrierwave

Rails 4 application with neo4j and the [neo4j.rb gem](https://github.com/neo4jrb/neo4j) using [carrierwave-neo4j](https://github.com/neo4jrb/carrierwave-neo4j) to attach images to a Report object.

```
2.0.0-p353 :001 > r = Report.find_by(name: 'my new report')
 => #<Report avatar: #<AvatarUploader:0x0000000643d950 @model=#<Report avatar: #<AvatarUploader:0x0000000643d950 ...>, created_at: Thu, 19 Nov 2015 14:25:58 +0000, created_by: nil, description: nil, embedJSON: nil, gridsize: nil, name: "my new report", tableau_link: nil, thumbnail_uri: nil, timestamp: nil, type: nil, updated_at: Thu, 19 Nov 2015 15:01:18 +0000, updated_by: nil>, @mounted_as=:avatar>, created_at: Thu, 19 Nov 2015 14:25:58 +0000, created_by: nil, description: nil, embedJSON: nil, gridsize: nil, name: "my new report", tableau_link: nil, thumbnail_uri: nil, timestamp: nil, type: nil, updated_at: Thu, 19 Nov 2015 15:01:18 +0000, updated_by: nil>
2.0.0-p353 :002 > File.open('app/assets/images/nd-gray.png') { |f| r.avatar = f }
 => #<File:app/assets/images/nd-gray.png (closed)>
2.0.0-p353 :003 > r.avatar.url
 => "/vagrant/fenrir/tmp/uploads/1447945541-17455-0224/nd-gray.png"
2.0.0-p353 :004 > r.save
 => true
2.0.0-p353 :005 > r.avatar.url
 => "/uploads/development/Report/nd-gray.png"
```

Everything is working fine at this point. But when I try to reload the Report object, the association is gone like it never happened.

```
2.0.0-p353 :006 > r = Report.find_by(name: 'my new report')
 => #<Report avatar: #<AvatarUploader:0x00000004205108 @model=#<Report avatar: #<AvatarUploader:0x00000004205108 ...>, created_at: Thu, 19 Nov 2015 14:25:58 +0000, created_by: nil, description: nil, embedJSON: nil, gridsize: nil, name: "my new report", tableau_link: nil, thumbnail_uri: nil, timestamp: nil, type: nil, updated_at: Thu, 19 Nov 2015 15:05:53 +0000, updated_by: nil>, @mounted_as=:avatar>, created_at: Thu, 19 Nov 2015 14:25:58 +0000, created_by: nil, description: nil, embedJSON: nil, gridsize: nil, name: "my new report", tableau_link: nil, thumbnail_uri: nil, timestamp: nil, type: nil, updated_at: Thu, 19 Nov 2015 15:05:53 +0000, updated_by: nil>
2.0.0-p353 :007 > r.avatar.url
 => nil
2.0.0-p353 :007 > r.avatar.path
 => nil
```

Switching to :aws upload instead of :file works fine for uploading, but has same missing association.

Here's my carrierwave class object.

```
#app/uploaders/avatar_uploader.rb
class AvatarUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base
  # Choose what kind of storage to use for this uploader:
  storage :file

  # Override the directory where uploaded files will be stored.
  def store_dir
    "uploads/#{Rails.env}/#{model.class}/"
  end

  # Add a white list of extensions which are allowed to be uploaded.
  def extension_white_list
    %w(jpg jpeg gif png)
  end
end
```

And the carrierwave initializer

```
#config/initializers/carrierwave.rb
CarrierWave.configure do |config|
  config.storage    = :file
  config.aws_bucket = ENV['S3_BUCKET_NAME']
  config.aws_acl  = 'private'

  config.aws_credentials = {
    access_key_id:     ENV['S3_KEY'],
    secret_access_key: ENV['S3_SECRET'],
    region:            ENV['S3_REGION'] # Required
  }

  # The maximum period for authenticated_urls is only 10 minutes.
  # config.aws_authenticated_url_expiration = 60 * 60 * 24 * 7

  # # Set custom options such as cache control to leverage browser caching
  # config.aws_attributes = {
  #   expires: 7.days.from_now.httpdate,
  #   cache_control: 'max-age=60480'
  # }

  config.cache_dir = "#{Rails.root}/tmp/uploads/" # To let CarrierWave work on heroku

  # config.fog_directory    = ENV['S3_BUCKET_NAME']
  #config.s3_access_policy = :public_read   # Generate http:// urls. Defaults to :authenticated_read (https://)
  #config.fog_host         = "#{ENV['S3_ASSET_URL']}/#{ENV['S3_BUCKET_NAME']}"
end
```

And finally, the Report model itself

```
#app/models/report.rb
class Report
  include Neo4j::ActiveNode
  searchkick word_start: [:name], autocomplete: [:name]
  validates_presence_of :name
  validates_uniqueness_of :name, case_sensitive: false

  property :avatar, type: String
  mount_uploader :avatar, AvatarUploader

  def search_data
    {
      name: name,
      description: description
    }
  end

  property              :name
  property              :description
  property              :tableau_link
  property              :type
  property              :thumbnail_uri
  property              :gridsize
  property              :timestamp
  property              :embedJSON
  property              :created_at
  property              :updated_at
  property              :created_by
  property              :updated_by
  has_many :in,         :terms
  has_one  :in,         :office

  def selectable_terms
    @selectable_terms = []
    self.terms.each do |t|
      @selectable_terms << { id: t.id, text: t.name }
    end
    @selectable_terms.to_json
  end

  def update_terms(param_terms)
    param_terms ||= []
    term_instances = []
    param_terms.each do |t|
      term_instances << Term.find_by(name: t)
    end
    term_instances
  end
  def aggro_extro
    embedJSON.present? ? JSON.parse(embedJSON) : Hash.new
  end
end
```

A reason I can think of is that we're using the :name field as our unique identifiers. Maybe carrierwave is looking for the UUID instead?

Another possibility is that carrierwave is caching the assocation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up scrapping Carrierwave and going with [Paperclip](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip). The gems we're using with paperclip are as follows for anyone else having trouble with getting image uploads to play nice with neo4j.rb. The connector gem for paperclip is the neo4j.rb team's [paperclip-fork](https://github.com/neo4jrb/neo4jrb-paperclip)

```
gem 'rails', '4.0.2'

gem 'neo4j', '~> 4.1.1'

gem 'neo4jrb-paperclip', github: 'subvertallchris/neo4jrb-paperclip', require: 'neo4jrb_paperclip'
gem 'aws-sdk-v1'
```

The new Report model-

```
class Report
  include Neo4j::ActiveNode
  include Neo4jrb::Paperclip

  has_neo4jrb_attached_file :avatar,
                            storage: :s3,
                            s3_permissions: :private,
                            default_url: '/assets/images/reports-icon-white.svg',
                            s3_credentials:
                              Proc.new { |a| a.instance.s3_credentials }
  validates_attachment_content_type :avatar, 
                                    content_type: ['image/jpg',
                                                   'image/jpeg',
                                                   'image/png',
                                                   'image/gif']
  # Rather than rename our variables in our secrets file, just rename them here
  def s3_credentials
    {
      bucket: ENV['S3_BUCKET_NAME'],
      access_key_id: ENV['S3_KEY'],
      secret_access_key: ENV['S3_SECRET']
    }
  end
```

Answer (score 2):

I just tried it and it seemed to work.  I'm guessing you're using an older version of the `neo4j` / `neo4j-core` gems though because when I try to use your model it points out that you haven't specified a `type` option.  That was required as of version `5.0.0`.  Can you update to the `5.2.0` series to see if that fixes the issue?   Also be aware that `6.0.0` will be coming out very shortly (the release candidate is already out).

Something else that I would mention is that you should probably specify an index for your `name` property in your model.  That should help when querying by name.  Since you are doing the `validates_uniqueness_of` you might even want to specify a constraint.  The constraint won't make sure that values are unique in a case-insensitive manner, but it will do some of the constraining of uniqueness for you at the database level.  You'll still want the `validates_uniqueness_of` with `case_sensitive: false`.  See the following docs:

http://neo4jrb.readthedocs.org/en/5.2.x/ActiveNode.html#indexes
http://neo4jrb.readthedocs.org/en/5.2.x/ActiveNode.html#constraints

Also note that constraints automatically create indexes, so you don't need to specify both (in fact in 6.0.0 we don't let you do that anymore).

Comment: Our app is indeed using `gem 'neo4j', '~> 4.1.1'`. Thanks for the quick reply Brian! We ended up going with paperclip and having great success with it.